# Why doesn’t VSCode autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

Once VSCode autocompletes fine, once it does not complete my text.

I would like VSCode to autocomplete for example if I write an Array, I would like to show the available methods for arrays (JavaScript).

Also can someone tell me what I need to download to autocomplete the JSX tags, too (in React)?

Comment: Please provide some minimal example code and steps the reproduce the case where VS Code does not offer auto completions

Answer (score -1):

Since javascript is a loosely typed language, IDEs (including but not limited to VSCode) can't figure out much about your code and so can't provide good autocompletion. There's not much you can do about this, except use another language. [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) is one you might consider. It's a superset of javascript, adds in type annotations, and has good integration with VSCode and its intellisense autocompletion.

Comment: While it is true VS Code is not able to offer correct intellisense for all JavaScript (especially highly dynamic code) it does provide IntelliSense in most real world cases. If VS Code does not provide IntelliSense in some JavaScript code where you think it should, [open an issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new/choose). You do not need to use TS to get IntelliSense